# てからに in 大学を出てからにしたら　meaning

Tags: particle-に, て-form, particle-から

> 父 :　どうしたんだ？
> 母 :　ゆき(Name of a person) が大学をやめて劇団の仕事やるって言ってるのよ。
> 父 :　劇団の仕事 ?　ああ、ずいぶん熱心にやっているからな。
> 母 :　**大学を出てからにしたら**といったんだけど…

What is the usage of に in 出てからに

Is it に indicating time ? (When Yuki's finished the university)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it に indicating time?

No. ～にする has several meanings, and here it means "to choose~~" or "to decide on~~", not "to do at [point in time]". The に here cannot be "at (point of time)", since the に for "at [point in time]" cannot be used with から; you don't say 「～てから**に** + Verb」「*大学を出てから**に**働く」 to mean "Verb + after ～ing" "work after graduating".

> 大学を出てから**にする** *Lit.* choose/decide on after graduating from university
> → choose to do so after graduating from university

Similar examples:

> いつ**に**しますか？ --  授業が終わってから**に**します。
> *Lit.* When will you choose? -- I choose/decide on after class ends.
> cf. いつしますか？ -- 授業が終わってからします。
> *Lit.* When will you do (it)? -- I'll do (it) after class ends.
>
> いつ**に**する？ -- 明日**に**する。
> *Lit.* When will you choose? -- I'll choose tomorrow.
> どれ**に**する？ -- あれ**に**する。
> *Lit.* Which will you choose? -- I'll choose that one.

Related:

- [Interpretation of 物語にしようと考えている](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/50601/9831)
- [しとけ and sentence translation](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13892/9831)

Answer (score -1):

In this case, the particle "に" indicates specific time. It works the same as "に" in "8時**に**起きた" (I woke up at 8am.)
In your example, the skelton is "**Specific timeに**(劇団の仕事を)する" meaning "Do (the job in a theatre company) **at specific time**."
Japanese often puts relative time to this place. "大学を出てから" means "After graduating the university" and it can be set after the particle "に". Thus

> 大学を出てからにしたら？
> How about doing it after graduating the university?

Comment: この「に」は「8時に練習する」「5月に旅行する」の「に」ではなく「合格にする」「風呂にする」の「に」だと思います。そもそも「8時からに練習する」とは言えませんし。

Comment: なるほど！たしかに、「する」以外ではつかえないですね。@Chocolateさんの「-にする」で「選ぶ」ような意味になるというのは納得です。Thanks for the correction!